# Suppress the cmd window called while installing the setup in batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, batch-processing, silent-installer

I'm trying to install sql server silently using batch script.
But while running the batch file, it opens two cmd windows.One might be of the batch file itself and the other is of setup.
How to suppress the window called by another application?
I have tried using start, but that isn't working.

Following is the code I'm currently using:-

```
@ECHO off

echo Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 >> %temp%\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt

"%~dp0\setup.exe" /ConfigurationFile="%~dp0\ConfigurationFile.ini"
```

Comment: Have you tried start  /Min  ?  .

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? If I'm installing anything, I'd expect a window to pop up.

Comment: Usually installers (here `setup.exe`) have special switches for silent installations like `/s`. Find out more about `setup.exe` and its options.

Comment: @Supriya By the way: The batch file path referenced with `%~dp0` ends already with a backslash. Therefore each backslash after this argument reference should be removed in both strings.